# Is it possible to password protect apache directory with Google 2 Factor Authentication

Tags: ubuntu, vps, apache2

I know how to password protect apache directories with htaccess .

Is it possible to authenticate protected directory with Google 2 Factor ?

Comment: Yes, take a look at https://github.com/itemir/apache_2fa